# 64-bit integers changed to floating point using JSON::XS::encode_json in Perl

Tags: json, perl, integer, 64-bit

My Perl version supports 64 bits.  I'm receiving JSON data from multiple sources, then I'm decoding it, processing it, and then I re-encode it in order to save the data in a MySQL queue for further processing by a different server.

All the data includes 64-bit integers as identifiers.  Sometimes, under some circumstances which I don't understand, the 64-bit integers are changed to floating point values by **JSON::XS::encode_json**.  For instance, `393074769794314240` would be changed for `3.93074769794314e+17`.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it an option to encode the identifier as a string in the original JSON? For example `"123"` instead of `123`?

Comment: Yes, it could be an option.  However, I feel really uncomfortable not understanding why the value changes from integer to float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can replicate the problem if the integer is used somewhere in a floating point context. It's sufficient to use the number in a floating point operation, e.g. adding another float to it. Here's a sample script:

```
use strict;
use JSON::XS qw(encode_json);
use Devel::Peek;

{
    my $x = { number => 4_999_999_999_999_999};
    Dump $x->{number};
    warn encode_json $x; # encodes number as integer
}

{
    my $x = { number => 4_999_999_999_999_999};
    my $y = $x->{number} + 0.1;
    Dump $x->{number};
    warn encode_json $x; # encodes number as float
}
```

On my FreeBSD amd64 system I get

```
SV = IV(0x80180a458) at 0x80180a468
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 4999999999999999
{"number":4999999999999999} at /tmp/json3.pl line 22.
SV = PVNV(0x80184d930) at 0x801813408
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,NOK,pIOK,pNOK)
  IV = 4999999999999999
  NV = 5e+15
  PV = 0
{"number":5e+15} at /tmp/json3.pl line 29.
```

A workaround is to use something like `$x->{number} += 0;` before the `encode_json` call — this would remove the NV value (the floating point value), and JSON::XS would again see only a IV (integer value).

Comment: Thank you very much.  `$x->{number} += 0;` did the trick for now.  Now I just have to understand why it changes to floating point context.

Comment: `+ 0.1` is just one possibilty. It could also be `printf "%f\n", $x->{number}` or `log($x->{number})` or `$x->{number} ** 2`...

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate your problem.

```
use Config      qw( %Config );
use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );
use JSON::XS    qw( encode_json decode_json );

print $Config{uvsize} * 8, "-bit ints\n";
my $n = 393074769794314240;
printf("%.20g\n", 0+$n);
Dump($n);
my $json = encode_json([$n]);
print "$json\n";
Dump(decode_json($json)->[0]);
```

Outputs:

```
64-bit ints
393074769794314240
SV = IV(0x4c8d90) at 0x4c8da0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 393074769794314240
[393074769794314240]
SV = IV(0x1dd130) at 0x1dd140
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 393074769794314240
```

Unless I use it as a floating point number, say by replacing

```
printf("%.20g\n", 0+$n);
```

with

```
printf("%.20g\n", $n);
```

Going forward:

- It's unlikely to help, but you could try upgrading JSON::XS.
- Provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.
- Provide the output of `perl -V:ivsize`.

Comment: The output for `perl -V:ivsize` is `ivsize='8';`.  I guess that means 64 bits.

Comment: Then you must have floats instead of integers, perhaps from using printf %f like I mentioned, perhaps due to some other floating point operation. Did you take a look at your code?

Comment: Yes, it's weird.  The shift happens when I compare the value to another value, but that other value is not used as a float either.  That other value is a shared variable (I'm using threads)... maybe all shared variables are treated as floats.